# Packaging Python Flask-electron Application

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, electron, electron-packager

I just created an electron app which is powered by Flask and sqlite3.

It works nice when I run the app in terminal but when I build this app with electron-packager, It succeed but the app does not work.

Getting Sql Database error,
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: licenseCheck

How do I package My Application. Please Guide me.

My File structure is follows

- Package.json
- index.html
- PyModules

  - Api.py
  - database.db - sqlitedb
- login.html
- main.js